# Joining multiple tables (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, many-to-many

I have this database diagram:

[image]

I was trying to create a query that performs some joins between these tables and result in something like this:

```
||name_|| ||Type # 1|| ||Type #2|| ||Ability #1|| ||Ability #2||
```

(the last four columns represent the types' and abilities' names, no their ID. Also,  type #2 and/or ability #2 may be null depending on the pokémon)

I am totally stuck. How should I do this?

Comment: You are trying to do a cross tab query. If you can be sure that each row in Kanto has at most two types and two abilities, you would probably find it easier to simply add two Type columns and two Ability columns to Kanto. On the other hand, if each row can have an unlimited number of Types and Abilities (requiring the many-to-many structure) then a cross-tab will be unsuitable anyway, and you should access the Types and Abilities in separate queries.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to want to start by joining the tables:

```
select k.name_,
  t.type,
  a.ability
from kanto k
left join kantotype kt
  on k.pokemonid = kt.pokemonid
left join types t
  on kt.typeid = t.typeid
left join kantoability ka
  on k.pokemonid = ka.pokemonid
left join abilities a
  on ka.abilityid = a.abilityid
```

If you need help learning joining syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

This will give you a list of all of the names, and their type and ability.

If you want to rotate the values that you get into columns, then you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to *pivot* the data:

```
select k.name_,
  max(case when t.typeid = 1 then t.type end) Type1,
  max(case when t.typeid = 2 then t.type end) Type2,
  max(case when a.abilityid = 1 then a.ability end) Ability1,
  max(case when a.abilityid = 2 then a.ability end) Ability2
from kanto k
left join kantotype kt
  on k.pokemonid = kt.pokemonid
left join types t
  on kt.typeid = t.typeid
left join kantoability ka
  on k.pokemonid = ka.pokemonid
left join abilities a
  on ka.abilityid = a.abilityid
group by k.name_
```

In each one of the `case` expressions you will want to identify the `id` to transform:

```
 max(case when t.typeid = 1 then t.type end)
                          ^-- replace with your actual value
```

Comment: Thanks indeed! just one question: what are those 'max' for?

Comment: @Mudkip if you want to transform the data from rows into columns, then you will need to use an aggregate function with a case to select the value for each `name`.  This is how you pivot data into columns from rows.

Comment: Hey bluefeet, thanks again for your help on this query. By the way, I tried some modifications on the query, and I've got something like this:
select k.name_ Name,
  max(case when (t.typeid = 1 or t.typeid = 7) then t.type end)  "Type #1",
  t.type "Type #2",
  a.ability "Ability #1",
  a.Ability "Ability #2"
from kanto k
left join kantotype kt
  on k.pokémonid = kt.pokémonid
left join types t
  on kt.typeid = t.typeid
left join kantoability ka
  on k.pokémonid = ka.pokémonid
left join abilities a
  on ka.abilityid = a.abilityid
group by k.name_, t.type, a.Ability

(continue right below)

Comment: (continue...)
and it returns something like this:
http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/833/queryresult.png

as you can see, there are many repeated records. Like on the 'Bulbasaur' row, instead of returning ||Bulbasaur||Grass||Poison||Overgrow||Null||, it returns like is shown on the image. Is there any way to correct this? Please, if you don't understand what I'm saying, let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mudkip This might be easier if you could create a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3) with your tables and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your approach and have your database query return something like:

```
||name_|| ||Type|| ||Ability||
```

instead of

```
||name_|| ||Type # 1|| ||Type #2|| ||Ability #1|| ||Ability #2||
```

In other words, return types and abilities as records (rows) instead of columns. For this, see bluefeet query.